# Spring Boot RequestMapping not working after first Pathvariable

Tags: spring, spring-boot, request-mapping

There are two set of data: **provinces** and **cities**.

The controller for provinces works properly. After posting with this method:

```
@RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.POST, value="/provinces")
public void addProvince(@RequestBody Province province) {
    provinceService.addProvince(province);
}
```

and get it with this method:

```
@RequestMapping("/provinces")
public List<Province> getAllProvinces( ) {
    return provinceService.getAllProvinces();
}
```

the object I posted shows on my browser.

```
{
    "id": "ks",
    "name": "Kangso",
    "description": "Peace River and So City"
}
```

However, after posting a **city** to that province:

```
@RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.POST, 
        value="/provinces/{provinceId}/cites/")
public void addCity(@RequestBody City city, 
        @PathVariable String provinceId) {
    city.setProvince(new Province(provinceId, "", ""));
    cityService.addCity(city);
}
```

with the method in **CityService**:

```
public void addCity(City city) {
    cityRepository.save(city);
}
```

and read it with the method:

```
@RequestMapping("/provinces/{provinceId}/cities")
public List<City> getAllCities(@PathVariable String provinceId) {
    return cityService.getAllCities(provinceId);
}
```

and this request:

> http://localhost:8080/location/provinces/ks/cities/

The posted object was not showing.

No error came out while compiling or sending the requests, and the RequestMapping for cities worked like other requests:

```
Mapped "{[/provinces/{provinceId}/cites/],methods=[POST]}"
Mapped "{[/provinces/{provinceId}/cities]}"
Mapped "{[/provinces]}"
Mapped "{[/provinces],methods=[POST]}"
```

I'm not sure whether the city is properly posted, and now I'm also trying to check what was actually posted in the CityService with eclipse STS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One issue to start is that your path is `/provinces/{provinceId}/cites/`, and should be `/provinces/{provinceId}/cities/`. I don't believe that is the core of the issue, however, I do believe that is why you aren't seeing any errors.

I believe that, if your path was correct, you would get an error that the `Province` (as defined by `new Province(provinceId, "", "")`) is not a managed entity. You can't relate that province to a city, and so on, because it's not persisted. Once persisted, you'd have an ID, and that would allow a relationship to be created.

Your method is creating a new empty Province, and therefore is not doing anything with the `provinceId` parameter. You need to take that parameter, and try to get a province object first.

```
@RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.POST, 
            value="/provinces/{provinceId}/cities/")
    public void addCity(@RequestBody City city, 
            @PathVariable String provinceId) {

        Province p = provinceService.findOne(provinceId);

        if (p != null) {
            city.setProvince(p);
            cityService.addCity(city);
        } else {
            // probably should throw a not found error here for the province
        }

    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice. Although it finally shows up after corresponding the misspelling, it is better to find the province first.